# @AfterThrowing not work as expected

Tags: java, spring, aop

I want to use AOP to intercept all runtime exceptions thrown in service layer and rethrow as domain exceptions.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionWrapperInterceptor {

    @Pointcut("within(*.service.*)")
    public void onlyServiceClasses() {}

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "onlyServiceClasses()", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw DatabaseException
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "onlyServiceClasses()", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw ServiceException
    }

}
```

The problem here is that, with a subclass of DataAccessException, the runtime execute the wrong method. There is an elegant solution to this?

Spring Version: 4.2.4.RELEASE

P.S. A single generic method (read from other questions) with a lot of instanceof is not elegant for me ;-)

Thanks
Francesco

Comment: By "wrong method" you meant, that both methods are executed, right?

Comment: No. Only the 'intercept(RuntimeException)' method.

Comment: Can you check my answer and share what is different in your case? You didn't share Spring version, definition of `onlyServiceClasses` and other details...

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. ;-)

Comment: this is a good question and a good learning experience (+1), but just consider the whole "rethrow everything as a domain exception" thing is a relic of pre-spring bad old days and probably can be done without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, that your expectation is wrong (that only one intercept method will match similarly as for method overloading).

But while `RuntimeException` is parent of `DataAccessException` both methods are executed...

**spring.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

</beans>
```

**AopTest**

```java
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.xml");
        MyService ms = ac.getBean(MyService.class);
        try {
            ms.throw1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ms.throw2();
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyAspect**

```java
package test;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw DatabaseException
        System.out.println("DAE");
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw ServiceException
        System.out.println("RE - " + ex.getClass());
    }

}
```

**MyService**

```java
package test;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {

    public void throw1() throws DataAccessException {
        throw new MyDataAccessException("test");
    }

    public void throw2()  {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    static class MyDataAccessException extends DataAccessException {

        public MyDataAccessException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }

    }
}
```

and in log there is:

```
DAE
RE - class test.MyService$MyDataAccessException
RE - class java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Maven dependencies:**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

[From Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering):

> When two pieces of advice defined in the same aspect both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined (since there is no way to retrieve the declaration order via reflection for javac-compiled classes). Consider collapsing such advice methods into one advice method per join point in each aspect class, or refactor the pieces of advice into separate aspect classes - which can be ordered at the aspect level.

When I tried following modification of `MyAspect`:

```
package test;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw DatabaseException
        System.out.println("DAE");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("DAE"); // added
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw ServiceException
        System.out.println("RE - " + ex.getClass());
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("RE"); // added
    }

}
```

log changed to:

```
DAE
RE - class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
RE - class java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and when modified to `Exception` I got:

```
package test;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw DatabaseException
        System.out.println("DAE");
        throw new Exception("DAE2"); // changed
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw ServiceException
        System.out.println("RE - " + ex.getClass());
        throw new Exception("RE2"); // changed
    }

}
```

the log was

```
DAE
RE - class java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I believe, that solution to your "problem" is to have two Aspects instead of one and define the ordering:

```
package test;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class DaeAspect implements Ordered {

    public int getOrder() {
        return 200;
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw DatabaseException
        System.out.println("DAE");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("DAE2"); // based on my testing, this stops second aspect to apply
    }

}
```

and

```
package test;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ReAspect implements Ordered {

    public int getOrder() {
        return 100;
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
        //throw ServiceException
        System.out.println("RE - " + ex.getClass());
        throw new IllegalAccessException("RE2");
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that the flow here is different from mine. You simply log and the interceptor execute all. I, in the first method throw another exception that not match with the second method.

Comment: As I wrote, you are not sharing important details. I tried to throw `IllegalArgumentException` but it was very similar, I'll mention this in answer...

Answer (score 4):

How about using an `@Around` advice? You can simply use type-safe `try-catch` therein, no need to use any `instanceof` or reflection.

Here is some sample code which I compiled using AspectJ instead of Spring AOP because I am not a Spring user. The pointcut should be the same anyway.

**Helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.service;

public class DatabaseException extends RuntimeException {
    public DatabaseException(Throwable arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.service;

public class ServiceException extends RuntimeException {
    public ServiceException(Throwable arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }
}
```

**Driver application (plain Java, no need to use Spring):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.service;

import java.util.Random;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptParseException;

public class Application {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                application.doSomething();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        switch (RANDOM.nextInt(3)) {
            case 1: throw new ScriptParseException("uh-oh", null);
            case 2: throw new IllegalArgumentException("WTF");
            default: System.out.println("doing something");
        }
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import de.scrum_master.service.DatabaseException;
import de.scrum_master.service.ServiceException;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionWrapperInterceptor {
    @Pointcut("within(*..service..*) && execution(* *(..))")
    public void onlyServiceClasses() {}

    @Around("onlyServiceClasses()")
    public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        try {
            return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        }
        catch (DataAccessException dae) {
            throw new DatabaseException(dae);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw new ServiceException(re);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
doing something
de.scrum_master.service.DatabaseException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptParseException: Failed to parse SQL script from resource [<unknown>]: uh-oh
doing something
de.scrum_master.service.DatabaseException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptParseException: Failed to parse SQL script from resource [<unknown>]: uh-oh
doing something
de.scrum_master.service.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WTF
de.scrum_master.service.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WTF
de.scrum_master.service.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WTF
de.scrum_master.service.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WTF
doing something
```